# Use CSS class in DOT NET High Chart to change PlotOptionsBar

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, highcharts

I am using Stacked Bar chart from Dot Net High Chart,
i want to use **CSS** to change Box of bar chart to Triangle , 
i tried in Formatter but its not working.
i am using ASP.NET and c# 
where I can use CSS??
any other way to do it??
[image: i want to do this.]

here is my code of chart

```
.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions


              {
                  Bar = new PlotOptionsBar
                  {
                      Stacking = Stackings.Percent,
                      BorderWidth = 2,
                      BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Coral,
                      Shadow = true,
                      DataLabels = new PlotOptionsBarDataLabels
                      {
                          Enabled = true,
                          Formatter = "function() { return this.series.name; }",
                          Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
                          Style = "fontSize: '13px', fontFamily: 'Verdana', fontBold: 'true', color: 'Black'"

                      },

                      PointWidth = 35,

                      Point = new PlotOptionsBarPoint { },
                  }


              })
```

Comment: You would need to change the Highcharts Javascript library to achieve that. What it does is to generate a canvas (image), which turns to be the chart. So, it's all about drawing.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: Changing HighChart Javascript will effect on each and every graph in project.

Comment: Exactly. But that's the only approach I can see. Unless you find a way to play with the generated canvas afterwards.

Comment: @MelanciaUK : I think i got the Better way to deal with it i am using CSS. its working

Comment: Good to know you have found a simpler way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be help to some one like me :)

```
.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
              {
                  Bar = new PlotOptionsBar
                  {
                      Stacking = Stackings.Percent,
                      BorderWidth =0,
                      BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray,
                      Shadow = false,

                      DataLabels = new PlotOptionsBarDataLabels
                      {
                          Enabled = true,
                          Formatter = "function() { return '<div class=\"Test\"/></br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+this.series.name;}",
                          Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
                          UseHTML=true,
                          Style = "fontSize: '12px', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontBold: 'true', color: 'Black'"
                      },
                      PointWidth = 35,
                      Point = new PlotOptionsBarPoint { },
                  }
              })
```

CSS code : for Test class:

```
 .Test {
        height:35px;
        width:80px;
        background-image:url("../../Images/Arrow.gif");
        background-size:cover;
        vertical-align:central;
        text-align:center;
        align-content:center;
        font-size:smaller;
        color:black;
    }
```

and My image is This image as transference back ground where white color is.
[image: This image as transference back ground]

And Finally i got this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unforutnately it is not possbile, because Highcharts return chart in SVG / VML, so using CSS is not correct. You can try to use scatter series, including triangle marker.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.marker.symbol
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter

Comment: I cant change the Graph type :(

Comment: set type of series or in chart object.

Comment: I am already using stacked bar chart. i cant change it. because it changes application functionality that depend on this graph

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possbile in stacked bar.